# IDE for Pl/SQL development

Tags: oracle, debugging, plsql

Is there any free IDE for Pl/SQL development

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I use [SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/database/sql_developer/index.html) every day to develop packages. Whilst it's not perfect, it's got some useful features:

- Syntax highlighting;
- Autocompletion;
- Debugging (although not of live requests as far as I can tell);
- Simple connection configuration (JDBC-based as well as TNSNAMES);
- ...

It's also free, unlike the (admittedly better) [Toad](http://www.toadsoft.com/) mentioned previously.

Comment: +1 SQL Developer for me too. One thing that SQL Developer has over other IDEs is that you can have multiple connections open at once.

Answer (score 10):

[Toad](http://www.toadsoft.com/) gets reasonable comments from the developers around me that have to work with Oracle. Everyone hates [Oracle SQL developer](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/database/sql_developer/index.html). I have little personal experience.

Comment: Agree. SQL Developer is rubbish. But still better than nothing.

Comment: **** SQL Developer has had extensive improvement since the time of this post ****

Comment: @StephaniePage - I agree I think it has got recently much better - version 3+

Comment: version 3.2 is still a crap. Editing table rows via editor is very inconvenient: cursor does not jump to the next row after deleting a row. Object list is not refreshed in db object list pane after creating new db object (for example table). SQL/PLSQL code editor is also very crappy, was unable to find how to open another sql/pl code editor window

Comment: Toad is the best, because it has a lot of tools and it is NEW!

Answer (score 10):

I am using [PL/SQL Developer](https://www.allroundautomations.com/plsqldev.html) from Allround automation, too.

I kinda hate it dearly for all its bugs and that we paid a full year maintenance w/o seeing anything new in that period.
But for some rather strange reason it still beats the hell out of all the other outrageously overprized and underfeatured tools for PL/SQL.
And I am not talking about Oracle administration, which it can do quite good as well, thx to how fast one can script things in it.
Its focus is PL/SQL, not point & click table creation. But than, my Grand Ma could build a tool for managing tables, users, etc. A good code editor is not as easy. *g*

One thing, besides the countless little bugs that face every time is, that it is completely ignorant to the fact, that Oracle has an escape syntax for non-standard identifiers.
You can't do much using its GUI with such objects but have to resort to the command window or  any other editor to script it yourself.

btw, the fact that I still use it and prefer over its alternatives doesn't reflect very well on  the market of commercial Oracle IDEs, IMO.
I think for writing DB code it is better than anything from any DBMS I have come across so far.
It has very little GUI support for stuff, but its different code editors are very capable and productive.

Comment: Same. I feel that you get more bang for the buck instead of the more expensive alternative, Toad.

Comment: I am as well. Somehow, 6 years after this comment, it still holds true... I don't understand how there isn't a better IDE for the most expensive Database :(

Answer (score 3):

I personally like http://www.allroundautomations.nl/plsqldev.html

Quite usefull for PL/SQL and Oracle in general. But not free.

Comment: I don't think that one is free

Comment: It's not free but it's relatively inexpensive, much cheaper than TOAD and IMHO better than TOAD.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Tools is a withdraw PL/SQL IDE that is lightweight and prompt, and it's unconstrained. Although one dimension it's absent is a debugger agree.

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Tools](http://www.sqltools.net/) is a free PL/SQL IDE that is lightweight and fast, and it's free.
Although one feature it's missing is a debugger support.

Answer (score 0):

There's also the open source plugin for NetBeans, named [PL/SQL Editor](http://code.google.com/p/pl-sql-editor/).

It's currently (version 2.1) very rudimentary, requires a live database to work on (no offline work with on-disk PL/SQL script sources) and I couldn't get the navigation ("Go To Declaration") to work on my Oracle 10 application.

Comment: Anyone has worked with IntelliJ DataGrip? I would like to hear some comments. I would agree SQL Developer could be better, they have spent so much time and still its formatting capabilities complete disaster. Every time when I format, I get different results:)

Answer (score 0):

I have been using Squirrel SQL for years and like it b/c it's database independent.  it does have some limitations but if I need something with more DBA tools I would also use SQL Developer.