# Need Help Choosing development tool for Oracle DB,

Tags: database, oracle, debugging, toad

We are looking for a development tool for oracle DB.

Most of our work on the DB will be done with PL/SQL procedures, so we need to debug them.
We will also need some minor Administration capabilities, like monitoring the session.

We got a recommendation to use Toad. 
There are several versions.
Which version of toad suites us the most?
Are there any other noteworthy tools?

What do you recommend?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [IDE for Pl/SQL development](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/304716/ide-for-pl-sql-development)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used and particularly likes the following two:

- [PL/SQL developer](http://www.allroundautomations.com/plsqldev.html?gclid=CLf_ktus9qYCFUbf4AodEDBYEw) - paid
  software, simple UI, great for
  creating/editing/debugging PL/SQL as
  well as admin activities.
- [Oracle SQL
  developer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/overview/index.html) - free, Java based,
  right from Oracle. Great for PL/SQL
  creation/debug.

Good luck!